# How to trim out sequence of blank-spaces?

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

Considering we have few strings:

```
s1 = "dasbdk        "
s2 = "asdnkal asn knkl nkn dvklsn     "
s3 = "    jbjkbasd nklnkln     "
```

**Q1:**

How can the blank-spaces **in the end only** be trimmed out to have the following result:

```
s1 = "dasbdk"
s2 = "asdnkal asn knkl nkn dvklsn"
s3 = "    jbjkbasd nklnkln"
```

**Q2**

How can any 2-or-more sequence of blank-spaces be trimmed out to have the following result:

```
s1 = "dasbdk"
s2 = "asdnkal asn knkl nkn dvklsn"
s3 = "jbjkbasd nklnkln"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen `StringTrim[]`?

Comment: StringTrim[] does only Q2, right?

Comment: @SuTron `StringTrim` can take a second argument to target any pattern, and so can do Q1 and Q2.

Comment: The most natural way seems to be simply: StringReplace[string, " " -> ""]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented, `StringTrim` for example will do the job.

For example :

```
StringTrim[s3]
StringTrim[s3, StartOfString ~~ WhitespaceCharacter ..]
StringTrim[s3, WhitespaceCharacter .. ~~ EndOfString]
```

return

```
"jbjkbasd nklnkln"
"jbjkbasd nklnkln     "
"    jbjkbasd nklnkln"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**

```
Column[StringReplace[#, " " .. ~~ EndOfString -> ""] & /@ {s1, s2, s3}]
```

> ```
> dasbdk
> asdnkal asn knkl nkn dvklsn
>     jbjkbasd nklnkln
> ```

**Q2**

```
Column[StringTrim[#] & /@ {s1, s2, s3}]
```

> ```
> dasbdk
> asdnkal asn knkl nkn dvklsn
> jbjkbasd nklnkln
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As already noted for Q2 the best solution is of course `StringTrim`. For Q1 here is an alternative using regular expressions:

```
stringTrimAtEnd = StringReplace[#,RegularExpression["\\s*$"] :> ""] &
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: keep deleting blank spaces from the end until they're gone (not very elegant but it works):

```
s3 = "    jbjkbasd nklnkln     "    
While[Characters[s3][[-1]] == " ", 
     s3 = StringJoin@Delete[Characters[s3], -1]]`
```

Q2: if you use `StringReplace[]` you can also delete multiple blank spaces in the middle of the String:

```
StringReplace["   asd   nkal asn  knkl nkn dvklsn     ", 
 " " ~~ " " .. -> ""]
```